# How to remove "Double braces {{}}" in a property of dynamic type during deserialization (ASp.Net Core MVC)

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-core, json-deserialization, jsonconvert

When deserializing a string, the curly braces are duplicating and this is disturbing the reading of some fields. I've tried everything, but I can't serialize correctly, without duplicate curly braces.

I already tried to do it like this:

```
dynamic values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(storedEvent.Data);
```

The storedEvent.Data property is of type string and contains this information:

```
"{\"PaisId\":31,\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelRemovedEventList\":[{\"Id\":6,\"PaisId\":31,\"PaisNomePtBr\":\"\",\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoId\":5,\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoNome\":\"Município\",\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoOrigemId\":5,\"Timestamp\":\"2022-11-24T20:16:15.6020289-03:00\",\"MessageType\":\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelRemovedEvent\",\"AggregateId\":6},{\"Id\":5,\"PaisId\":31,\"PaisNomePtBr\":\"\",\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoId\":1,\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoNome\":\"Estado\",\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoOrigemId\":null,\"Timestamp\":\"2022-11-24T20:16:15.6580242-03:00\",\"MessageType\":\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelRemovedEvent\",\"AggregateId\":5}],\"Timestamp\":\"2022-11-24T20:16:16.1892039-03:00\",\"MessageType\":\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelHierarquiasRemovedEvent\",\"AggregateId\":31}"
```

Result obtained (Duplicate curly braces):

```
{{
  "PaisId": 31,
  "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelRemovedEventList": [
    {
      "Id": 6,
      "PaisId": 31,
      "PaisNomePtBr": "",
      "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoId": 5,
      "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoNome": "Município",
      "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoOrigemId": 5,
      "Timestamp": "2022-11-24T20:16:15.6020289-03:00",
      "MessageType": "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelRemovedEvent",
      "AggregateId": 6
    },
    {
      "Id": 5,
      "PaisId": 31,
      "PaisNomePtBr": "",
      "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoId": 1,
      "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoNome": "Estado",
      "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoOrigemId": null,
      "Timestamp": "2022-11-24T20:16:15.6580242-03:00",
      "MessageType": "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelRemovedEvent",
      "AggregateId": 5
    }
  ],
  "Timestamp": "2022-11-24T20:16:16.1892039-03:00",
  "MessageType": "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelHierarquiasRemovedEvent",
  "AggregateId": 31
}}
```

Expected:

```
{
  "PaisId": 31,
  "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelRemovedEventList": [
    {
      "Id": 6,
      "PaisId": 31,
      "PaisNomePtBr": "",
      "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoId": 5,
      "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoNome": "Município",
      "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoOrigemId": 5,
      "Timestamp": "2022-11-24T20:16:15.6020289-03:00",
      "MessageType": "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelRemovedEvent",
      "AggregateId": 6
    },
    {
      "Id": 5,
      "PaisId": 31,
      "PaisNomePtBr": "",
      "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoId": 1,
      "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoNome": "Estado",
      "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoOrigemId": null,
      "Timestamp": "2022-11-24T20:16:15.6580242-03:00",
      "MessageType": "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelRemovedEvent",
      "AggregateId": 5
    }
  ],
  "Timestamp": "2022-11-24T20:16:16.1892039-03:00",
  "MessageType": "PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelHierarquiasRemovedEvent",
  "AggregateId": 31
}
```

Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: What are you trying to do after Deserializing that you are having trouble with?

Comment: When deserializing, double keys are appearing. Example: "{{" and "}}"

Comment: It is not a problem that you are converting it to a `object` (dynamic) because you see it when debugging. I mean, are you having trouble accessing one of the properties?

Comment: I believe the dynamic object is getting in the way. I was successful in the tests using "ExpandoObject": JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(storedEvent.Data, typeof(ExpandoObject));
The problem is that it returns an array of objects and I don't know how to get the property values.

Comment: "Result obtained (Duplicate curly braces)" How have you obtained this result? Can you show the code pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dynamic` is not a good option to work with `Json objects` dynamically
For this, you can use `Jobject` as follows

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;



string jsonStr= "{\"PaisId\":31,\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelRemovedEventList\":[{\"Id\":6,\"PaisId\":31,\"PaisNomePtBr\":\"\",\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoId\":5,\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoNome\":\"Município\",\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoOrigemId\":5,\"Timestamp\":\"2022-11-24T20:16:15.6020289-03:00\",\"MessageType\":\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelRemovedEvent\",\"AggregateId\":6},{\"Id\":5,\"PaisId\":31,\"PaisNomePtBr\":\"\",\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoId\":1,\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoNome\":\"Estado\",\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaTipoOrigemId\":null,\"Timestamp\":\"2022-11-24T20:16:15.6580242-03:00\",\"MessageType\":\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelRemovedEvent\",\"AggregateId\":5}],\"Timestamp\":\"2022-11-24T20:16:16.1892039-03:00\",\"MessageType\":\"PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelHierarquiasRemovedEvent\",\"AggregateId\":31}";

var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);

//access properties
var paisId = obj["PaisId"];

//Access to PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelRemovedEventList
var paisList = obj["PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelRemovedEventList"].ToList();

//search on PaisDivisaoAdministrativaNivelRemovedEventList
var result = paisList.FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x["Id"] == 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix the code that returns the double braces string. If you don't have access to this code,  the only way to get rid of double braces is to use string function

```
storedEvent.Data=storedEvent.Data.Substring(1,Data.Length-2);
```

after this you can use your code if you like, but I don't like dynamic, IMHO it is better to use Parse and sqware brakets to get data.